# Determining the average occurrence of each letter per word

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a program that determines the frequency of occurrence of each letter from a series of words using arrays. It will output the average occurrence of each letter per word **and that is my problem**.

```
Input:
The quick brown fox jumps over{enter}
the lazy dog{enter}
1{enter} //1 terminates the program and shows the output

Output:
a: 0.11  b: 0.11  c: 0.11  d: 0.11  e: 0.33
f: 0.11  g: 0.11  h: 0.22  i: 0.11  j: 0.11 
k: 0.11  l: 0.11  m: 0.11  n: 0.11  o: 0.44
p: 0.11  q: 0.11  r: 0.22  s: 0.11  t: 0.22
u: 0.22  v: 0.11  w: 0.11  x: 0.11  y: 0.11
z: 0.11
```

This is my code so far:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
        {
            Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
            int y=0;
            int[] alArray = new int[26];
            while(y==0)
            {
                String in = scn.next().toLowerCase();
                for (int x=0; x<in.length(); x++) 
                {
                     char chr=in.charAt(x);
                     int val=(int) chr;
                     if (val>=97 && val<=122)
                     {
                         alArray[chr-'a']++;
                     }
                }
                for (int x=0; x<alArray.length; x++) 
                {
                    if(alArray[x]>0)
                    {
                        char chr = (char) (x+97);
                        System.out.println(chr+": "+alArray[x]);

                    }         
                }
            }
        }
```

### I/O

```
Input:
Hello World

Output:
e: 1
h: 1
l: 2
o: 1
d: 1
e: 1
h: 1
l: 3
o: 2
r: 1
w: 1
```

Comment: The first sample is unclear: there is no `h` in the input yet the output shows `h:0.22`...

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: @RossDrew Check it again?

Comment: @user3152606 you check it again "and that is my problem" isn't a question.

Comment: Sooo, the problem appears to be that you've only got as far as doing the count, and then it does the letter count word-by-word instead of for the whole phrase. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average of how many times each letter appears then you need to do an average on them and not just count them.  i.e. after you count the occurrences:-

```
for (int x=0; x<in.length(); x++) { ... }
```

You have to get the average which is number of actual appearances divided by possible appearances

```
for (int x=0; x<alArray.length; x++) {
{ 
   if(alArray[x]>0)//avoid division by zero
   {
     //for each letter, do (actualOccurences / possibleOccurences )
     alArray[x] = alArray[x] / in.length;
   }
}
```

Although there should perhaps be a separate array for averages and this could be combined into your last loop and possibly the removal of white-space characters from this calculation.

**Other problems**

If you don't want the output to be shown until `-1` is enterred, you will need to move the last loop `for (int x=0; x<alArray.length; x++)`  outside the main loop `while(y==0)`.  This would also mean you would need to keep a sum of all phrases entered as `possibleOccurences` so that you can use it to average once the main loop is done.

Lastly, there is no functionality to enter the `-1` to exit so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `actualOccurences / possibleOccurences`?